# Find all primes for which $p^p - 2$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory

Find all primes for which $p^p - 2$ is a perfect square.
Let $p^p-2=a^2.$

We know $a^2 \equiv 0,1\pmod{3}$

If $a^2 \equiv 1\pmod{3}$, then $p^p \equiv 0\pmod{3}\implies p=3$ which is a solution.

Now, if $a^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3},$ then $p^p \equiv 2\pmod{3}$.

By Fermat's theorem, $p^p \equiv p \pmod{3}$ as $p$ is coprime to $3$.

So, we have $p$ is of the form $3k+2.$

But what to do next?

Comment: $p=3$ works, since $$3^3-2=25=5^2$$

Comment: Well, you know that $-2$ is a square $\pmod p$ which gives you $p\equiv 1,3\pmod 8$.  Have you found any examples with $p>3$?

Comment: I checked with Maple up to the 605th prime and got no other examples.  Maple got tired at this point.  @lulu

Comment: @B.Goddard  Thanks.  I don't see any reason why there wouldn't be examples but who knows?

Comment: Think you missed the $2$ in $p^p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ on the penultimate line. It'd be easier to read if you spaced out your working, btw.

Comment: @lulu Related to Catalan's conjecture. I'm not an expert, and memory may be wrong, but I seem to remember it has also been proven that $3^3$ and $5^2$ are the only powers with a distance of $2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer  Ah, good point.

Comment: @DanielFischer To the best of my knowledge, it is still unknown whether there are only finitely many powers at distance $d$, for any $d$ different than $1$, unless it's some recent news.

Comment: @DanielFischer, can you provide source of the proof?

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra No, sorry. And by Wojowu's comment above, it seems likely that memory was wrong and it's still open.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that for $p\neq 3$ must be $p=9k+t$ where $t\in\{1,2,4,5,7,8\}$ we must also have that $p=6n+1$ or $p=6n+5$ since $p\neq 2,3$.

Now by Euler theorem $t^6=1\pmod{9}$ if $p=6n+1$ we have that $$(9k+t)^{6n+1}\equiv t\pmod{9}$$ since the only $t$ such that $t-2$ is a quadratic residue mod $9$ is $t=2$ we must have $t=2$ but $6n+1\neq 9k+2$ hence no solutions.

If $p=6n+5$ we have that $$(9k+t)^{6n+5}\equiv t^5\pmod{9}$$
The only $t$ such that $t-2$ is a quadratic residue mod $9$ is $t=5$ so $p=9k+5$
this implies that the number is of the form $p=18q+5$ but again by euler theorem
$$(18q+5)^{18q+5}$$
Looking mod $4$ we see that $q$ must be even so $(36q+5)^{36q+5}$
Now looking mod $108$ and using Euler we have that
$$(36q+5)^{36q+5}\equiv (36q+5)^5\equiv 65,29,101\pmod{108}$$
But $x^2+2\not \equiv 65,29,101\pmod{108}$ or differently $x^2\not\equiv 63,27,99$